# Get registrations per class even if nobody has registered

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a task that I'm getting a bit hung up on with SQL Server and wondered if anybody could help.

Task:
Within the database, I need to create a stored procedure with the name `ClassRegistration`. The columns of the result set for this stored procedure need to be as follows:

1. `[Class]` – The name of the class to be taught
2. `[Teacher Name]` - The name of the person teaching the class
3. `[Registrations]` - The number of pupils who have registered to take the class
4. `[Number Paid]` - The number of pupils who have paid their fees for the class

Tables:

1. `[Teacher]` : `Teacher_ID` (PK), `TeacherName`
2. `[Class]` : `Class_ID` (PK), `ClassName`, `Teacher_ID` (FK)
3. `[ClassRegistration]` `Student_ID` (FK), `Class_ID` (FK), `HasPaidFees`
4. `[Student]` `Student_ID` (PK), `StudentName`

The college needs to know about every class, even if nobody has yet registered.

My SQL so far:

```
Create  PROCEDURE ClassRegistration
AS
SELECT DISTINCT 
    c.ClassName, 
    t.TeacherName, 
    COUNT(cr.Student_ID) As Registrations, 
    COUNT(case when cr.HasPaidFees = 1 then 1 else null end) As NumberPaid
FROM 
    Class As c, 
    Teacher As t, 
    ClassRegistration As cr, 
    Student As s
WHERE
    (c.Class_ID = cr.Class_ID) 
AND (cr.Student_ID = s.Student_ID)
GROUP BY c.ClassName, t.TeacherName
```

I can create the stored procedure fine but the output doesn't look correct, any help would be greatly appreciated :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to join to Student and you had 4 tables but only 2 join criteria. This is one of the pitfalls of [using old `table,table` join syntax instead of proper, explicit joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). I also:

- listed your "inner" tables first
- added `dbo.` prefix to table references
- added `SET NOCOUNT ON` to the procedure
- removed the unnecessary `DISTINCT`
- simplified the `CASE` expression

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ClassRegistration
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT c.ClassName, t.TeacherName, 
    COUNT(cr.Student_ID) As Registrations, 
    COUNT(NULLIF(cr.HasPaidFees, 0)) As NumberPaid
  FROM dbo.Class As c
  INNER JOIN dbo.Teacher As t
  ON t.Teacher_ID = c.Teacher_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ClassRegistration As cr
  ON c.Class_ID = cr.Class_ID
  GROUP BY c.ClassName, t.TeacherName;
END
GO
```

Comment: Would it be possible to filter the results using a HAVING clause?

Comment: That depends on what you mean. Are you wanting to filter on, say, a specific teacher, a specific class, or a specific number of registrations?

Comment: Filtering on registrations. Just tried it out and it seems to work :).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find classes even where you have no registrations you need to use a [`left outer join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT  Distinct c.ClassName, t.TeacherName, COUNT(cr.Student_ID) As Registrations, COUNT(case when cr.HasPaidFees = 1 then 1 else null end) As NumberPaid
FROM    Class As c
INNER JOIN Teacher As t
on c.Teacher_ID = t.Teacher_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN ClassRegistration As cr
ON (c.Class_ID = cr.Class_ID)
INNER JOIN Student As s
ON  (cr.Student_ID = s.Student_ID)
GROUP BY c.ClassName, t.TeacherName
```

(note that I have rewritten your other joins as `INNER JOIN`)